# Show in a ListView a TextView and Image from Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is what I have in my DataBase
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd1YC.jpg)

I want to display from the data the fields "pet name" (TextView) and "imageRef" (imageView) into a ListView, When I run this code, I don't have any errors ,But it is still doesn't show me the text or the image from the data (its shows an empty page).

Can someone **please** tell me what I did wrong?!
Thanks ♥

I have a ModelClass:

```
public class ModelClass {
    String Nume,imagine;

    public String getNume() {
        return Nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        Nume = nume;
    }

    public String getImagine() {
        return imagine;
    }

    public void setImagine(String imagine) {
        this.imagine = imagine;
    }

    public ModelClass(String nume, String imagine) {
        Nume = nume;
        this.imagine = imagine;
    }
}
```

My Adapter :

```
public class MyAdapt extends ArrayAdapter<ModelClass> {
    private Activity context;
    private int resource;
    private List<ModelClass> listImage;

    public MyAdapt(@NonNull Activity context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<ModelClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        listImage = objects;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPetName);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv2);

        tvName.setText(listImage.get(position).getNume());
        Glide.with(context).load(listImage.get(position).getImagine()).into(img);


        return v;

    }
    public void addElement(ModelClass element) {

        listImage.add(element);
    }
}
```

And the page where the list view is:

```
public class PetFeed2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<ModelClass> imgList;
    private ListView lv;
    private MyAdapt myAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pet_feed2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imgList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading list image...");
        progressDialog.show();

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();


                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    ModelClass img = snapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                    imgList.add(img);
                }


                myAdapter = new MyAdapt(PetFeed2.this, R.layout.custumpet, imgList);

                lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            ModelClass img = snapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                            myAdapter.addElement(img);
                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need read the fields `pet name` and `imageRef` but the ModelClass object hasn't those variables for matching with those fields. So, you need to do the following in your ModelClass:

```
public class ModelClass {
    @PropertyName("pet name")
    String Nume;
    @PropertyName("imageRef")
    String imagine;

    //...
```

With that you matching the field `pet name` with the variable `Nume` and the same with the other

Edit:

Now in your Adapter change this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
```

with

```
View v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
```

Comment: After I changed it, i could see my error, its said that there is a problem with the line :   "ModelClass img = snapshot.getValue(ModelClass.class);"      in the page where my LIstview is. Do you know how I can fix it? :) And no, i dont know FirebaseUI, should i learn it ?

Comment: You were right, now the app doesn't crushed, but for some reason I still have nothing on the listview :(

Comment: I think you need to do one change in your adapter. Please, see my answer

Comment: you are so nice , I'm sorry I am bother you so much !! I changed in the adapter the line you said but its still shows me an empty page :(, Do you know if i have another problem?

Comment: Why do you have this `mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(...` twice? I don't know but it could be the problem. Anyway take a look this guide to use  ArrayAdapter: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView It can be usefull